# rails sとguardを同時に実行したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`rails s`でサーバーを立ち上げて、別タブで`guard`を実行しているのですが、
`rails s`したときに`guard`も走らせることはできないでしょうか。
毎回2つコマンドを入力するのがめんどくさいです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ddollar/foreman

foremanというgemが便利です
Procfileというファイルに実行したいコマンドを羅列しておけば
foreman startコマンドで一気に実行してくれます

Procfileのサンプル

> web:    bundle exec rails s
>   guard:  bundle exec guard

Answer (score 0):

```
rails s &; guard
```

とすればサーバーをバックグラウンドで立ち上げた後に`guard`の実行ができます。
ただ、そうすると終了する時に`fg`コマンドで`rails s`をフォアグラウンドに持ってきてから終了しないと立ち上げたままになってしまいます。

上記コマンドをうつのがめんどくさい時は

```
alias rg='rails s &; guard'
```

と `~/.bashrc`にかきbashを再起動すれば `rg` で rails server と guard を起動することができます。